# system program problem detected error when log in screen

Tags: 14.04, system

seems like my problem is little bit different than other people 
I found the error 'system program problem detected' in log in page.

 and my original password did not recognized by the system. 
in this situation how should I access to the terminal and fix this issue? >
(and also mouse point get really slow in the log in page)

===================solution=============================
 I did not tried this solution yet but this might be the answer

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG4deLa_vK8